# Flexible img, inside a fixed width div, with an absolute div above it

Tags: html, css

To be more specific, here's an image showing what I'm trying to do:

[image]

A specific width centered div contains an img with a text div above it on the top-right corner.
I'm facing two problems here.

- If I set a fixed width to the container instead of 100%, the img
  inside it ignores resizing when you play around with the browser
  width.
- And if I set the container width to 100%, the img resizes    without
  any problem but the position of the text div ignores its container, so if you resize the browser it appears to be fixed inside the screen.

Anyway to get these two to get along inside the div?

Thanks!

Comment: share your code or a jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: You might want to take a look at flexbox. Here's a good tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: when you use `width: 1060px;` on the container, the responsiveness will stop right at 1060px client width. When you want a different behaviour use `max-width: 1060px` http://jsfiddle.net/pgC5k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built a quick sample that should mimic my understanding about your question.
[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5EX6/2/)

You may remove the boarders from `css`, they are only for the demonstration, so you may identify each element's boarder while re-sizing the browser

The key to center an `img` inside a container is to give that container `text-align:center;` then you need to apply `max-width: 100%;` along with `margin:auto` to the `img` so to re-size the image dynamically while playing around with the browser's width

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla hendrerit magna eros, sed adipiscing neque sollicitudin ac. Aenean in nisi faucibus erat bibendum elementum. Quisque blandit nisi et accumsan dapibus. Cras placerat sagittis lacinia. Quisque eu erat tortor. Donec imperdiet massa nulla, at aliquam lacus rhoncus auctor. Integer vitae nunc sollicitudin, elementum orci et, rhoncus orci. Sed ut adipiscing mi.              
        </div>

        <img src="http://www.outcomes.somee.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
        max-width: 980px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid green;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #text {
         position: absolute;
         right: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        width:200px;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    }
```

Comment: So it seems the only thing I did wrong is using width instead of max-width for the container class...
Thanks!